# Non-homogenous differential equation help

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

8. a) Given $x = e^u$ and $$x^2\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} - 4x \frac{dy}{dx} + 6y = 12$$ show that $$\frac{d^2y}{du^2} - 5 \frac{dy}{du} + 6y = 12$$

I was able to do this:
$x = e^u$

$$\frac{dx}{du} = e^u = x $$

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dy}{du} \frac{du}{dx} = \frac{1}{x}\frac{dy}{du}$$

$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = -\frac{1}{x^2}\frac{dy}{du} + \frac{1}{x}\frac{d^2y}{du^2}\frac{du}{dx} = -\frac{1}{x^2}\frac{dy}{du} + \frac{1}{x^2}\frac{d^2y}{du^2}$$

$$x^2\left(-\frac{1}{x^2}\frac{dy}{du} + \frac{1}{x^2}\frac{d^2y}{du^2}\right) -4x\left(\frac{1}{x}\frac{dy}{du}\right) + 6y = 12 $$

$$-\frac{dy}{du} + \frac{d^2y}{du^2} - 4\frac{dy}{du} +6y = 12 $$

$$\frac{d^2y}{du^2} - 5\frac{dy}{du} + 6y = 12 $$

part b is where I got stuck:

b) Hence solve the equation $$x^2\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} - 4x\frac{dy}{dx} + 6y = 12$$ given that $y(1) = 7$ and $y(2) = 14$

$$\frac{d^2y}{du^2} - 5\frac{dy}{du} + 6y = 12 $$

auxiliary equation: $\lambda^2 - 5λ + 6 = 0 $

Hence $\lambda = 3, 2$

Complementary function: $$y = Ae^{3u} + Be^{2u}$$

particular integral in the form $y = c$

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = 0 = \frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$$

$$6C = 12 $$

$$C = 2$$

general solution: $$y = Ae^{3u} + Be^{2u} + 2 $$

where I began to get stuck:

replacing $u = \ln x$ means you get left with

$$y = Ax^3 + Bx^2 + 2$$

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = 3Ax^2 + 2Bx $$

$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = 6Ax + 2B $$

my teacher told me to "substitute this into the solution of the DE and just apply the conditions"

(this is where I think I may me wrong, I think I might have to equate the differential equation to 0 after substituting)

through substituting these values into the differential equation you get:

$$x^2 (6Ax + 2B) - 5(3Ax^2 + 2Bx) + 6 (Ax^3 + Bx^2 + 2) = 12 $$

$$ 6Ax^3 + 2Bx^2 -15Ax^2 - 10Bx + 6Ax^3 + 6Bx^2 + 12 = 12 $$

$$ 12Ax^3 + 8Bx^2 -15Ax^2 - 10Bx = 0 $$

This may resolve very simply, but I didn't want to try without knowing I was doing the correct thing.

Comment: This is way easier than you think. Your general solution $y(x)=Ax^3+Bx^2+2$ is correct. Now, using the boundary conditions, you obtain:
$$7=y(1)=A\cdot 1^3+B\cdot 1^2+2=A+B+2$$
$$14=y(2)=A\cdot 2^3+B\cdot 2^2+2=8A+4B+2$$
Solve for $A$ and $B$, then plug it in to your general solution.

Comment: I appreciate you trying to use the formatting. Next time, use `$` or `$$` for the entire line, and never use `x` for multiplication

Answer (score 1):

You're correct that the general solution is

$$ y(x) = Ax^3 + Bx^2 + 2 $$

Using the given boundary conditions we have

\begin{align}
y(1) &= A + B + 2 = 7 \\
y(2) &= 8A + 4B + 2 = 14
\end{align}

or

\begin{align}
A + B &= 5\\
8A + 4B &= 12
\end{align}

Solving the above system gives $A=-2$, $B=7$